# Call global dynamic variable from a function

Tags: php

Is there a way to call a dynamic variable within a function that was set up outside the function, such as making it a global variable.

```
$a = 'test' 
$b = 'cat' 
$c = 'dog' 

debug_vars(['a', 'b', 'c']); 

function debug_vars( $arr ) { 
  $display = array();
  foreach($arr AS $v) { 
    GLOBAL ${$v}; 
    $display[$v] = $v; 
  } 
  print_r($display);
}
```

I would like it to show an array of [ 'a' => 'test', 'b' => 'cat', 'c' => 'dog' ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recreating the built in `compact` function, which already does what you want:

```
$a = 'test' ;
$b = 'cat' ;
$c = 'dog' ;

print_r(compact('a','b','c'));

//Array ( [a] => test [b] => cat [c] => dog )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Comment: This gives me what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there

```
$a = 'test';
$b = 'cat'; 
$c = 'dog' ;

debug_vars(['a', 'b', 'c']); 

function debug_vars( $arr ) { 
  $display = array();
  foreach($arr AS $v) { 
    GLOBAL ${$v};
    $display[$v] = ${$v};
    //             ^---^--------------- use the global ?
  } 
  print_r($display);
}
```

Output :

> Array ( [a] => test [b] => cat [c] => dog )

Althought this is working as expected, I do not recommend you to use global variables. This may lead easily to unmaintainable code. Try using another approach than globals.

Comment: This solution has an issue, if $v == "display"

Comment: This solution has an issue as soon as `GLOBAL` is used. Especially if the function is called with user input `debug_vars(['a', 'b', 'connectionstring']);` That's why i don't recommend using it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `variable variable` with the `$$` operator.

```
<?php
$a = 'test';
$b = 'cat'; 
$c = 'dog';
debug_vars(['a', 'b', 'c']); 
function debug_vars( $arr ) { 
    $debug = array();
    foreach($arr AS $v) {
        if ($v != 'debug') {
            GLOBAL $$v; 
            $debug[$v] = $$v;
        }
    } 
    print_r($debug);
}
```

Comment: This solution has an issue, if $v == "display"

Comment: It does >.<  ... patched.

Answer (score 0):

use `$GLOBALS[]`:

```
$display[$v] = $GLOBALS[$v];
```

-> http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

EDIT:

Using `global $$v` as mentioned in the other answers may have side effects if the var name is used locally.